# Better user interface options for SQL Server than Access

Tags: sql-server

A department within my company is currently using an Access front-end connected to a SQL Server back-end to for data entry and run to queries (that I have written - users have little to no technical knowledge).  Due to the popularity of this database that I created, additional departments have asked me to create something similar for them.  While I plan to continue using Access short-term, I have started to explore long-term solutions for a more professional UI than Access.  There are currently around ten users working in the Access front-end, but the number could easily go up to 100 within the next year or so.  Is Access my best option or are there others that I could research?

Comment: [LightSwitch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851953.aspx) was *meant* to be the "Access replacement" from MS. Unfortunately, it's now been [axed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lightswitch/2016/10/14/lightswitch-update/) (not that you'll read that in the documentation).

Comment: There are a lot of different options out there.  A good place to start is with a list.  Write down the good things Access is doing for you.  Detail where it is holding you back.  These pros/cons should help you evaluate each of the options.  There is no right/wrong answer but it helps if you pick a technology that a) plays to your strengths b) has a steady stream of available employees, in your local area & c) is popular.  Option C ensures you can find help on sites like this.

Comment: Very late to the party. There's always Appster by a company called Markster. It provides a nocode Windows interface, a bit like SSRS if you built a data-entry version for Windows.